# Passing all arguments of a function to another function

Tags: python, function, arguments

I want to pass all the arguments passed to a function(`func1`) as arguments to another function(`func2`) inside `func1`
This can be done with `*args, *kwargs` in the called `func1` and passing them down to `func2`, but is there another way?

Originally

```
def func1(*args, **kwargs):
    func2(*args, **kwargs)
```

but if my func1 signature is

```
def func1(a=1, b=2, c=3):
```

how do I send them all to func2, without using

```
def func1(a=1, b=2, c=3):
    func2(a, b, c)
```

Is there a way as in javascript `callee.arguments`?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136673/when-should-i-use-varargs-in-designing-a-python-api

Comment: I don't see how this could be useful...

Comment: it's not all that useful, but sometimes I write a function with lot of args, and and bored of copying them over and over.

Comment: @Mark no, not related, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @jcao219 this is useful when writing generic decorators that do not care about function args

Comment: @jcao219 - or if you're extracting common functionality to another function, and you don't what to change the existing external calling interface

Answer (score 75, accepted):

*Explicit is better than implicit* but if you really don't want to type a few characters:

```
def func1(a=1, b=2, c=3):
    func2(**locals())
```

`locals()` are all local variables, so you can't set any extra vars before calling `func2` or they will get passed too.

Comment: This will have the flaw that if you've created local variables before calling `func2`, then they will also be passed to `func2`.

Comment: maybe you could copy locals right at the beginning of the function?

Comment: Now I remember reading about `locals`. I was thinking too much about `vars()` and couldn't remember `locals()`. Should have read the documents. I guess vars() can be used too.

Comment: This would not work for class functions as it will get multiple values for self

Comment: @Bhaskar: Is there any way around that?

Comment: @Bhaskar, can you elaborate on the problem? I'm only seeing one copy of `self`, even when using multiple inheritance. What's the "this" that won't work, using `locals()` at all, or trying to save a copy of the result as a way to have a record after a local variable has been created?

Comment: Ouch, I hate this one.  The reason is that `locals()` is the wrong concept - you want to pass "all the parameters" not "all the local variables".  All sorts of innocent changes - like adding a local variable before this line, or moving a function to be a method or vice versa - can break this code.  More, the reader has to scratch their head to figure it out.

Comment: Is there a lean general solution to pass mixed parameters from arguments and keyword arguments?

Answer (score 13):

Provided that the arguments to func1 are only keyword arguments, you could do this:

```
def func1(a=1, b=2, c=3):
    func2(**locals())
```

Comment: Why only keyword arguments?

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, using `locals()` might cause you to pass on more variables than intended, if `func1()` creates new variables before calling `func2()`.

This is can be circumvented by calling `locals()` as the first thing and creating a copy of its contents, like so:

```py
def func1(a=1, b=2,c=3):
    parameters = locals().copy()

    d = parameters ["a"] + parameters ["b"]

    func2(**parameters) #the value of `d` is not passed to func2.
```

If we had made the function call like `func2(**locals())` then `d` would have been added as a parameter.

Comment: This doesn't work as intended, because `parameters` is a reference to `locals()` and will always show the same contents. The call to `func2` will have both `parameters` and `d` as arguments. To use this method, you have to change the first line in the function to `parameters = locals().copy()`. This gets a copy of the initial `locals()` contents and remains constant as long as you don't modify the arguments themselves.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, because this took me some time: the function lvl1 will *consume* var_a and var_b. Those variables will be removed from kwargs and will not be available to function lvl2 unless we copy them from locals and add them back to kwargs using the update method:

```
def lvl1(*, var_a, var_b, **kwargs):
    """Will print var_a, var_b and then call lvl2."""
    parameters = locals().copy()
    # right now var_a and var_b were consumed
    # and are not present within kwargs anymore
    # therefore the call to lvl2 function, which needs var_b, will fail
    # thats why we need to catch them from locals
    # and add back to kwargs
    kwargs.update(parameters)
    print(var_a)
    print(var_b)
    lvl2(**kwargs)

def lvl2(*, var_b, var_c, **kwargs):
    """Will print var_b, and var_c."""
    print(var_b)
    print(var_c)

# kwargs definition, we can name it anything
settings = {'var_a': 1, 'var_b': 2, 'var_c': 3}
# function call
lvl1(**settings)
```

This is specially useful in pipelines that call a lot of functions (lvl2) and we want to avoid repeating all those variable names on all function calls.