# Python: Passing functions with arguments to a built-in function?

Tags: python, refactoring

like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136915/python-passing-all-arguments-of-a-function-to-another-function) I want to pass a function with arguments. But I want to pass it to built-in functions.

Example:

```
files = [ 'hey.txt', 'hello.txt', 'goodbye.jpg', 'howdy.gif' ]

def filterex(path, ex):
  pat = r'.+\.(' + ex + ')$'
  match = re.search(pat, path)         
  return match and match.group(1) == ex)
```

I could use that code with a for loop and an if statement but it's shorter and maybe more readable to use filter(func, seq). But if I understand correctly the function you use with filter only takes one argument which is the item from the sequence.

So I was wondering if it's possible to pass more arguments?

Comment: Use a list comprehension. It will be faster than filter and easier to read

Comment: You have a couple typos.  It should `match = `, and `return True` (or you can just `return match and match.group(1) == ex`)

Comment: Thanks Matthew I adjusted it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def make_filter(ex):
    def do_filter(path):
        pat = r'.+\.(' + ex + ')$'
        match = re.search(pat, path)
        return match and match.group(1) == ex
    return do_filter

filter(make_filter('txt'), files)
```

Or if you don't want to modify filterex:

```
filter(lambda path: filterex(path, 'txt'), files)
```

You could use a list comprehension, as suggested by gnibbler:

```
[path for path in files if filterex(path, 'txt')]
```

You could also use a generator comprehension, which might be particularly useful if you had a large list:

```
(path for path in files if filterex(path, 'txt'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matthew Flaschen I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list comprehension that does the same thing

```
import os
[f for f in files if os.path.splitext(f)[1]=="."+ex]
```

Comment: Thanks I a lot gnibbler. I have list comprehensions in other parts of my code but it seems I didn't make the connection to my filter function. I'll use the 'I am new excuse'.